# NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find an element by using linktext and href but both did not worked for me. Bizarre is I was able to locate the element and do actions on the same element in the test environment but failing in dev environment. I don't see any difference in test and dev environment specs.

Code

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://*****.com");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.linkText("Register/Create an Account"))));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register/Create an Account")).click(); or
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='********']")).click();
```

Error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Register/Create an Account"}
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
Session ID: 8757a2e4-a195-4ce0-b043-0f6c3decacc8
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=31.0}]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:401)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:730)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:728)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$3.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$3.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
```

Comment: Not much we can do if you don't share any `html`

Comment: is the dev environment set up to automatically login, so you never land on the page with the target element?

Comment: Is the dev environment particularly slow?  you're only waiting for a hard coded time period...perhaps that's not long enough in dev?

Comment: @RemcoW Here you go 
<div class="widget-content widget-link-container" >
 <style>
  ...
 </style>
 <a class="widget-link" href="http://www.example.com" target="_parent">
  <span class="link-text">Register/Create an Account</span>
 </a>
</div>

Comment: @BreaksSoftware 
Dev environment is not set for automatic login, I will definitely land in login page where the element is visible. 
And the dev environment is not slow, I have tried with 30 seconds wait time as well.

Comment: These problems are REALLY annoying!  Can you debug this in the dev environment so that you can see what's happening?  if not, perhaps grab a screenshot on failure so that you can at least see what's up on screen.  Are the test and dev environments using the same brand/version of browser?

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I tried debugging on dev but couldn't figure out what's wrong. Everything works fine till it tries to find the element by link/xpath and then fails.
Test and Dev environment have same version of browser (IE11)

Comment: You may need to use a different locator.  Perhaps start with the grandparent of the span? something else that's unique.

Comment: In fact I tried with id (driver.findElement(By.id("root_Link-12-bounding-box")).click();) which is unique for the below Html 

`<div id="root_Link-12-bounding-box" class="widget-bounding-box nonresponsive" >
<div id="root_Link-12" class="widget-content widget-link-container"  >
<a class="widget-link" href="example.com" target="_parent" >
<span class="link-text">Register/Create an Account</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: And also tried finding the element by input type 'submit' (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();)

 `<input class="submit-login" type="submit" name="Login"     value="Login">'`

Comment: frameset HTML tag was the culprit which was blocking to identify the element since it does not allow requests from cross domain. Added `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("frame")));` to the test script to get this working. However, there is one more issue which is not getting the window handle of main window. I have tried with `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` to get the control back to main window and locate the elements present in main window but no luck.